How to calculate Nudged Elastic Band using Quantum Espresso
How do I calculate NEB using Quantum Espresso?
What input files do I need to do for NEB to run using quantum espresso? For example, if I want to calculate NEB for a graphene monolayer (12 C atoms)  with 5 images. As far as I know, I have to prepare the first and last images, so how about intermediate images, Where can I get them?

Does this official example help? Here, they provided a complete NEB calculation example with written explanations (check the README and .sh files therein along with the input files).

Thank you, Mr. Abdul Muhaymin, this example is not useful unfortunately
